# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: .aggregate() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongo-shell

i'm trying to execute **.aggregate()** function with this pipelines, but i got this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: User.find(...).select(...).sort(...).aggregate is not a function
```

```
const users = await User
            .find(findParams)
            .select(userResponse)
            .sort(sortParams)
            .aggregate([
                {$group: {_id: "$_id", dateCreated: {$first: "$dateCreated"}}},
                {$set: {dateCreated: {$dateToString: {format: "%d.%m.%G %H:%M:%S", date: "$dateCreated"}}}}
            ])
            .exec()
```

users is my collection from MongoDB. Do i need more pipelines to reject this error? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) returns a cursor on which you cannot invoke `.aggregate()`. You need to pass the aggregation pipeline directly to [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
                {$group: {_id: "$_id", dateCreated: {$first: "$dateCreated"}}},
                {$set: {dateCreated: {$dateToString: {format: "%d.%m.%G %H:%M:%S", date: "$dateCreated"}}}}
            ])
            .exec()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there  cursor methods, that  can replace collection methods like find(), sort() and can i execute my query with them

Comment: You can include `$sort` inside your aggregation pipeline: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Answer (score 1):

hello my friend aggregate() method is only used on schema just like below

```
const users = await User
        .aggregate([
            {$group: {_id: "$_id", dateCreated: {$first: "$dateCreated"}}},
            {$set: {dateCreated: {$dateToString: {format: "%d.%m.%G %H:%M:%S", date: "$dateCreated"}}}}
        ])
        .exec()
```

follow up this [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) you will get the better idea of aggregate() method